# Сложение двух массивов символов без повторений

Tags: c++, строки

Есть два массива символов, строки проще говоря, нужно сложить их без повторяющихся элементов, т.е. если дано: `"112пруу"` и `"341афж"`, то выдать должно `"12пру34афж"`, вроде бы решение на поверхности, но не получается никак(

Comment: Порядок важен? `1234ажпруф` не годится?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Чем вас не устраивали ответы, которые вам давали ранее на тот же вопрос?

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
string add(const string& a, const string& b)
{
    bool f[256] = { false };

    string res;
    for(unsigned char x: a)
    {
        if (f[x] == false)
        {
            res += x;
            f[x] = true;
        }
    }
    for(unsigned char x: b)
    {
        if (f[x] == false)
        {
            res += x;
            f[x] = true;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Для utf-8 так компактно уже не выйдет :-(

Comment: @avp Эт точно :) Тогда для того, чтоб `O(n)` сохранить, придется `unordered_set` использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Решение тупо в лоб: добавляем символы из исходных строк по одному, предварительно проверяя, есть ли он уже в выходной строке:

```
std::wstring concat_unique(std::wstring in1, std::wstring in2)
{
    std::wstring out = L"";
    for (auto i: in1 + in2) {
        if (out.find(i) == std::wstring::npos) {
            out += i;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Единственный минус - формально O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

`int main(){
    string s1 = "11245abc";
    string s2 = "298da";
    string res = "";
    unordered_set<int> used;
    for (auto s : s1 + s2){
        if (used.insert(s).second)
           res+=s;
    }
    cout << res<<endl;
    return 0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
string add(const string& a, const string& b)
{
    bool f[256] = { false };

    string res;
    for(unsigned char x: a)
    {
        if (f[x] == false)
        {
            res += x;
            f[x] = true;
        }
    }
    for(unsigned char x: b)
    {
        if (f[x] == false)
        {
            res += x;
            f[x] = true;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вопрос студенческий, то готового решения приводить не буду.
Вижу, все stl используют, будем тоже использовать stl.

Ключевое слово - "без повторяющихся". Используем std::set.
Читаем http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set
Нужно пройти сначала по первой строке, добавляя в set (читаем док, ищем какая функция добавляет) символы, затем по второй.
set автоматически содержит только уникальные символы и в порядке возрастания.
Вторым шагом нужно извлечь из set символы. 
Здесь нужно использовать итераторы.

```
for (set<char>::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
{ cout << ... }
```

На место многоточия поставьте разыменование итератора (как указатель).
Весь код должен уместиться у вас в пять строк.

Answer (score -1):

Здравствуйте! Для сложения двух строк используйте ф-ию `strcat(char*,char*)` в качестве первого аргумента поместите первый массив.
Если Вы хотите, что бы в исходном массиве не было одинаковых символов то так:

```
char* sum(char* m1, char* m2)
{
    int size;
    size = strlen(m1) + strlen(m2); //получаем общее кол-во символов
    char* m3 = new char[size]; //создаём динамический массив

    for (int i(0), ii(0), ic(0); i <= size; ic++, i++)
    {
        if (i < strlen(m1)) //для первого
        {
            int s = 0;

            for (int iii(0); iii <= i; iii++)
                if (m3[iii] == m1[i]) //если совпал
                {
                    s = 1;
                    ic--;
                    break;
                }

            if (!s)
            {
                m3[ic] = m1[i];
            }
        }
        else//для второго
        {
            int s = 0;

            for (int iii(0); iii <= i; iii++)
                if (m3[iii] == m2[ii]) //если совпал
                {
                    s = 1;
                    ic--;
                    break;
                }

            if (!s)
            {
                m3[ic] = m2[ii];
            }

            ii++;
        }
    }

    return m3;
}

int main()
{
    char m1[10] = "asdzxcs";
    char m2[10] = "dfjhsfsas";
    cout << sum(m1, m2);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Вот хороший сайт http://cppstudio.com/ , сам по нему начинал учиться

Comment: а вы вопрос внимательно прочитали?

Comment: @pavel, оу я подумал что это опечатка, сейчас перепишу, спасибо)

Comment: Возврат char *, работа с ним же, хотя в вопросе C++, ещё и утечка памяти

Comment: @int3 ну да, надо было вводить ещё однин массив и внего запихать строку из динамического, а потом у далять динамический. Пример не очень, согласен