# Два массива символов в один без повторов

Tags: c++, массивы, символы

Есть 2 массива символов, например '11245пру' и '298уе', вернуть должно '1245пру98уе', причем решить надо простыми средствами языка, вроде как банально через вложенный или пару циклов решить как-то можно, но не получается придумать рабочее((

Comment: Да что вы все, сговорились, что ли?! http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522546/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9